# Bootstrap 3: Span rows in a grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to do something pretty simple, but still have not been able to figure it out- even with all the snippets I have seen online.

In the following layout I want to span the panel on the right across 3 rows, how can I achieve this?

[image]

Here is my html:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>TEST</h1>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                BODY
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                FOOTER
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                BODY
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                FOOTER
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                BODY
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                FOOTER
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                BODY
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                FOOTER
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!--end grid -->

    <div class="row
        style="height: 300px;"
        ">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="panel panel-default panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Span ME</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    BODY
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    FOOTER
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you use JavaScript/jquery to calculate the height of the `col-md-2`, the only CSS options would be to..

**1) Use flexbox sizing..**

http://www.bootply.com/125623

*The downside is that this is not supported by all browsers (yet)*

2) **Use height 100%** on the "SPAN ME" panel and it's containers..

http://www.bootply.com/125613

*The downside is that it's set to 100% height of the browser, not the height of the left `col-md-2`*

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<div class="container">
<h1>TEST</h1>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-offset-10"></div>
<div class='col-md-2'>
  <div class="panel panel-default panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            BODY
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            FOOTER
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-10"></div>
    <div class='col-md-2'>
  <div class="panel panel-default panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            BODY
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            FOOTER
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class='col-md-2'>
  <div class="panel panel-default panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            BODY
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            FOOTER
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>



         <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="panel panel-default panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Span ME</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                BODY
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                FOOTER
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I actually want the panel to span the height of three of the panels on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's , the same i just added one panel:

```
    <div class="container">
 <h1> TEST </h1>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-offset-10"></div>
<div class='col-md-2'>
  <div class="panel panel-default panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            BODY
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            FOOTER
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-offset-10"></div>
<div class='col-md-2'>
  <div class="panel panel-default panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            BODY
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            FOOTER
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-10"></div>
    <div class='col-md-2'>
  <div class="panel panel-default panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            BODY
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            FOOTER
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class='col-md-2'>
  <div class="panel panel-default panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            BODY
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            FOOTER
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>



         <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="panel panel-default panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Span ME</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                BODY
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footerenter code here">
                FOOTER
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```